# logical indexing a vector based on custom condition

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I have a matrix called event of type double 6000 x 5350. The matrix is full of numbers which are codes. What I would like is to get a logical vector of where any element in a column is greater than or equal to 100.

The line of code below returns a logical vector which is what I am looking for however I am not interested if the element isnan.

```
 act_deal = isnan(event(:, i));
```

I would like to substitute the isnan condition for something like the below line. However this will only return the row number where this condition is true.

```
act_deal = find(event(:, i) >= 100);
```

Below is an simple example of what I am looking for.

```
 one column of event matrix
 50
 99
 100
 105
 23
 100
 62
```

the result I would like back is

```
 0
 0
 1
 1
 0
 1
 0
```

Comment: what happens if you omit the `find`? try just `event(:,i)>=100`

Comment: BTW, it is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical indexing!

```
act_deal = event(i,:)>=100
```

will give you the result you ask for here.

```
act_deal = event(i,event(i,:)>=100)
```

will give you the actual values.